# Use page.html.twig template variable in another twig template

Tags: theming

How do I call a **page.html.twig** template variable from the **book-tree.html.twig** template.

Using **kint**, I have found the variable, **nid** as in the screenshot below:

The '**nid**' is highlighted, but it is the '**x-default** value that is required.

[image]

This variable will be used in a **set** statement, comparing it to the **item.original_link.nid** to set an active class.

This page **nid** is not available within the **book-tree.html.twig** template.

As per Answer 1, I have created a `_preprocess` function in my subthemes .theme file as below:

```
function subtheme_bs_preprocess_book_tree(&$variables) {
 $variables['page_nid'] = 'Add code to get the node id variable';
}
```

The variable `page_nid` now shows up in the `book-tree.html.twig` array. The result is `'page_id' => string(36) "Add code to get the node id variable"` which is the static text I added.

I would like help on how to call the `nid` value from the `node.html.twig` template. I have tried several combinations:

`$variables['page_id'] = $variables['page']['content']['book_navigation']['#book_link']['nid']` 
But this and many other compinations I have tried all end with a:

`Notice: Undefined index: page in subtheme_bs_preprocess_book_tree()`

Maybe I need to call an `Available method` but have no clue as to how this is done.

Below is a screenshot of the `{{ kint() }}` output from the top of the `node.html.twig` file.

the value I need to target is the **115** in this line **'x-default' => value (3) 115**.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The book-tree.twig is rendered in its own scope.  It does not "know" any of the context it is being rendered in, so it can't tap into the variables from the page twig per se.  It only gets the variables you give it.  So you could implement a `THEME_preprocess_book_tree(&$variables)` hook to add it in.  `$variables['page_nid'] = // your code here` will make it available in twig as `{{ page_nid }}`.

However at the risk of being "that annoying guy" who tells you not to do things instead of just answering your question

> This variable will be used in a set statement, comparing it to the item.original_link.nid to set an active class.

Personally I would eschew this approach as it ends up placing logic inside the presentation layer.  I would rather use the hook to compare item nids to page nid, and add the active class to that item's `attributes` as appropriate.  That way the twig can be kept extremely "stupid", and simply dump out whatever attributes for all items, and those attributes will magically contain (or not contain) the appropriate classes.

Comment: **Thanks** for being "that annoying guy"  
Having read many other posts about twig templates, I will now have to read a lot more to understand the `_preprocess` process.  Many thanks.